# generate random number from an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

in mock test, i store id of questions in an array and i want when test start then it generate radomly id's from this array. when id is less then 10 then it generate correct number but when it store greater then 10 like 20,21,22.. then it also generate also number form 1-10. i want it generate random number from number which store in this array. thnax..

```
$ids= array('20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32',);
     $getIds=mysql_query("select * from mock_test_question where status='1' and question_level='FINAL' ") or die(mysql_error());
while($data=mysql_fetch_array($getIds))
{
    array_push($ids, $data['id']);
}
print_r($ids);
echo "</br>";
$rand_keys = array_rand($ids,5);
$_SESSION['quesid']=$rand_keys;
print_r($rand_keys);
```

Comment: Sorry can't understand.

Comment: i want $ids array generate random number between 20 to 32.. thnx..

Answer (score 2):

array_rand returns the KEYS (array positions) not the actual values. To get the values:

```
echo $ids[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = count($ids) - 1; # note that its -1 because array keys start from 0
echo $ids[rand(0,$count)];
```

here is a fast way to get random element from array

P.S> 
Here is complete code with generate of numbers and usage..

```
$ids = array();
for($i=20;$i<=32;$i++){ $ids[]=$i; }
$count = count($ids) - 1;

echo $ids[rand(0,$count)];
echo $ids[rand(0,$count)];
echo $ids[rand(0,$count)];
```

Comment: i don't want that it generate number from 0. i want it generate number from array elements..

Comment: What generation of 0 ? it will random pick array key and fetch its value from your array..

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a random number

```
$randomValues = array('20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32');
$randomValuesIndex = array_rand($randomValues, 1);
$randomValue = $randomValues[$randomValuesIndex];

echo $randomValue."\n";
```

An example loop that generates random numbers

```
$randomValues = array('20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32');

for ($i = 1; $i < 30; $i++)
{
    $randomValuesIndex = array_rand($randomValues, 1);
    $randomValue = $randomValues[$randomValuesIndex];

    echo $randomValue."\n";
}
```